# Appendix section position in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=magyar,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\vfill

\include{chapters.tex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------
%Appendix

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Függelék}
\renewcommand\thesection{F.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{F.\arabic{figure}}    
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\appendix
\include{appendix.tex}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

**chapters.tex**

```
\chapter{Chapter I}

\section{Section I}

\section{Section II}

\chapter{Chapter II}

\section{Section I}
```

**appendix.tex**

```
\chapter*{Függelék}

\section{First}

\section{Second}
```

[image]

tartalomjegyzék means: table of content

függelék means: appendix

As you can see Appendix section (F.1. First and F.2. Second) appears wrongly. How could I position it below the Appendix chapter?

Comment: Move the whole appendix code starting with the comment `%Appendix` into `appendix.tex` or replace `\include{appendix.tox}` by `\input{appendix.toc}`.

Comment: thanks, that is working for me